# Bootstrap Reset Button in btn-group

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap buttons which i have in a btn-group.

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class="btn  "data-toggle="button">Item1</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn  "data-toggle="button">Item2</button>
</div>
```

So at the moment (as i'm using data-toggle), when a button is pressed it goes into a highlighted mode. I now want a clear button, when that is tapped I would like the buttons to be reset. I've read the manual and see I have to use: `$().button('reset')`

However its just not working. Could someone please help with an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's simple... All you need to call is:

```
$('.btn-group button').removeClass('active');
```

This is essentially what the code does when you toggle it.

Comment: Following on from this - I'm now trying to do the oppposite however only on a specified button with id="specialButton"
$('.btn-group button').addClass('active');
Is the above correct and what do i place in the bracket with '.btn-group button'

Comment: Given you have marked the html with an id `<div class="btn-group" id="someId">` then you can use this format `$('#someId button').addClass('active');`